# Python - Use map when having function with 3 arguments

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I would like to convert the following in order to utilize the map function:

```
tmplist = [3434,34,342,123123,451414,124124,1234124]
b=1234
a=5234

 for i in tmplist:
          b, a = myfunc(b, a, i)
```

Please note that both b and a shall be overwritten in every iteration. The initial need for this question is to make the code more efficient. I am seeking for an implementation which will help me iteration a lot more faster than the above for-loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to update the a,b value on each iteration?

Comment: Yes i need to do that

Comment: Then why use `map`?
I don't think you'll have an easy to read code.

Comment: Because i would like to optimize it's execution time if possible

Comment: Rewrite your question to reflect exactly what you want, to use `map` with updating parameters...

Comment: `map` is defined as applying same function to sequence of arguments. If your case you're applying **different** functions for each case (even if difference is only constants `b` and `a`), moreover, new function **depends** on output of previous function. It's sequential in it's nature, and therefore not suitable for map operation. Even if someone would suggest an answer with using `map()` built-in, it still won't be a true map operation (as defined e.g. [on it's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(parallel_pattern))) , just some kind of dirty hack.

Comment: as it stands (i.e. wanting to use map), this is a pure [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Excuse me if you think that this is a common XYproblem, but it is not. All i am asking is if there is any quicker way to iterate through the list than the for-loop. If it is not clear enough i could articulate it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *reduction*, not a map. The appropriate function for reductions is `reduce`:

```
b, a = reduce(lambda ba, x: myfunc(ba[0], ba[1], x), tmplist, (b, a))
```

Note that this won't help with your efficiency problem. If you want to improve your code's efficiency, you'll need to make algorithmic improvements, or you'll need to eliminate Python-level code from the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately instead of improving the execution time it got worst with the reduce function. More specifically it raised the execution time for 10μsec.

Comment: @Captain_Harlock: Yes, and as I said, that's expected. `map` wouldn't help you either.